# Can't lauch selenium with a python script

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, launching

I am trying to lauch a Selenium scrit from a Python script and it gets stuck at "11:16:32.144 INFO - Launching Firefox..."

The Selenium server is running well, I also tried the Selenium IDE and it works. I am using Ubuntu lynx, Firefox 3.6.23, Selenium server 2.11.0

What do you think it could be ?

Thank you very much.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that Selenium can't find firefox somehow?

Is the process ending? or just hanging?

Try starting selenium runner manually, say from ipython, something like:

```
from selenium import selenium
sr = selenium(host, port, "*firefox*", url)
sr.start()
```

and see if you get an exception?